# How this algorithm actually works and thought process behind it?

Tags: python, algorithm

I came across this question as follows:

There are three integers a, b, c given in input. You have to convert the number a to b by performing the given operations:

1. Multiply a by c
2. Decrease a by 2.
3. Decrease a by 1.

You have to perform the above operations to convert the integer from a to b and find the minimum steps.
Note: You can perform the operations in any order.

I found this solution:

```
def rec(a,b,c):

    if a>=b:
        return ((a-b)//2+(a-b)%2)

    if b%c==0:
        return (1+rec(a,b//c,c))

    else:
        x=(b//c+1)*c;
        return ((x-b)//2+(x-b)%2+rec(a,x,c))


a,b,c=map(int,input().split())
print(rec(a,b,c))
```

The first condition check is easily understandable that if (a>=b) then we decrement a in steps of 2 until we reach b and if there is a remainder "1" we add it to the steps to compute the final output.

In second and third condition checks it successfully performs the required operation using the concept of recursion, but why recursion is used? Is it possible to do it without recursion? What is the use of x in third condition?

Comment: Ask its author?

Comment: This seems more like a maths problem so I do not think this is the place to ask for it.

Comment: @Matiiss Stackoverflow provides algorithm tag to ask questions regarding algorithm

Comment: @CutePanda well ok then

Comment: Try choosing some (small, manageable) values for a, b, c and work out what the optimal solution is. Then work out what the code does and see how it compares. This isn't a widely-known or reusable algorithm, it's just a one-off solution for a synthetic problem.

Comment: Note that for c==1 this is not going to work.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Assume input will be such that, solution always exists

Comment: in fact, disregard my removed comment, it is wrong

Comment: Break it down into smaller pieces and draw it on paper. Think it through with small values. Ask the author.

Comment: "I tried to understand but I don't, explain it to me" is too broad for Stack Overflow. You would find it more helpful to talk to a tutor or peruse a tutorial for the concepts and functions used in your algorithm. You should [edit] your question to ask a _specific_ question you have about the algorithm.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I have updated the question with the specific query I have, can you now help me with the answer? Regarding the tutorial thing you mentioned I know how each and every step in the code is executed but I wanted to know the intent and advantage behind using that I also know about the concept of recursion and use of function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some kind of logging, at each moment there really is only one possible route:

```py
def rec(a, b, c):
    if a >= b:
        # when a >= b, multiplying doesn't make sense,
        #   so subtract 2 as many times as needed
        #   then subtract 1 if the difference was odd
        print(f"from {a}, subtract 2 for {(a - b) // 2} steps, subtract 1 for {(a - b) % 2} steps to get {b}" +
              f" (this are {((a - b) // 2 + (a - b) % 2)} steps)")
        return ((a - b) // 2 + (a - b) % 2)

    if b % c == 0:
        # we have a < b, we need to multiply at least once to get from b/c to b,
        #   we still need to go from a to b/c
        print(f"first get {b // c}, then multiply by {c} to get {b}" +
              f" (this is 1 step)")
        return (1 + rec(a, b // c, c))

    else:
        # we have a < b and b isn't a multiple of c
        #   we need to get to a multiple of c that is larger then b, let x be this multiple
        #   we need to multiply at least once to get from x/c to x
        #   we will need subtractions of 2 and 1 to get from x to b
        #   we still need to go from a to x
        x = (b // c + 1) * c
        print(f"first get {x}, then subtract 2 for {(x - b) // 2} steps, subtract 1 for {(x - b) % 2} steps to get {b}" +
              f" (this are {((x - b) // 2 + (x - b) % 2)} steps)")
        return ((x - b) // 2 + (x - b) % 2 + rec(a, x, c))

a, b, c = map(int, input().split())
print("Total number of steps:", rec(a, b, c))
```

For example, for `4 29 5`:

```
first get 30, then subtract 2 for 0 steps, subtract 1 for 1 steps to get 29 (this are 1 steps)
first get 6, then multiply by 5 to get 30 (this is 1 step)
first get 10, then subtract 2 for 2 steps, subtract 1 for 0 steps to get 6 (this are 2 steps)
first get 2, then multiply by 5 to get 10 (this is 1 step)
from 4, subtract 2 for 1 steps, subtract 1 for 0 steps to get 2 (this are 1 steps)
Total number of steps: 6
```

PS: As the function is written with tail recursion, it can easily be transformed to a loop. Instead of giving the variables new values by recursion, the new values can be assigned localy in the loop:

```py
def rec(a, b, c):
    result = 0
    while a < b:
        if b % c == 0:
            result += 1
            b //= c
        else:
            x = (b // c + 1) * c
            result += (x - b) // 2 + (x - b) % 2
            b = x
    result += ((a - b) // 2 + (a - b) % 2)
    return result
```

A benefit of the recursive code, is that it is easier to convert to write the output in the correct order:

```py
def rec(a, b, c):
    if a >= b:
        steps2 = (a - b) // 2
        steps1 = (a - b) % 2
        if steps1 + steps2 > 0:
            print(f"from {a}" +
                  (f", subtract 2 for {steps2} steps" if steps2 > 0 else "") +
                  (f", subtract 1" if steps1 > 0 else "") +
                  f" to get {b}" +
                  f" ({steps1 + steps2} steps)")
        return steps1 + steps2

    if b % c == 0:
        prev_steps = rec(a, b // c, c)
        print(f"from {b // c}, multiply by {c} to get {b}" +
              f" (plus 1 step, totaling {1 + prev_steps} steps)")
        return 1 + prev_steps

    else:
        x = (b // c + 1) * c
        prev_steps = rec(a, x, c)
        steps2 = (x - b) // 2
        steps1 = (x - b) % 2
        print(f"from {x}" +
              (f", subtract 2 for {steps2} steps" if steps2 > 0 else "") +
              (f", subtract 1" if steps1 > 0 else "") +
              f" to get {b}" +
              f" (plus {steps1 + steps2} steps, totaling {steps1 + steps2 + prev_steps} steps)")
        return steps1 + steps2 + prev_steps
```

```
from 4, subtract 2 for 1 steps to get 2 (1 steps)
from 2, multiply by 5 to get 10 (plus 1 step, totaling 2 steps)
from 10, subtract 2 for 2 steps to get 6 (plus 2 steps, totaling 4 steps)
from 6, multiply by 5 to get 30 (plus 1 step, totaling 5 steps)
from 30, subtract 1 to get 29 (plus 1 steps, totaling 6 steps)
```

Comment: Do you think the version without recursion is easier to grasp?

Comment: The code without the use of recursion worked fine. Thanks!